# Python: Pandas: Rolling Windows - mean() works but variance() doesn't?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, nan

I have the following data which is recorded in seconds: http://pastebin.com/wBSJWYn2

I want to capture various summery statistics like the mean, variance, etc on it for 1 minute intervals. So I'm running these functions on  `sensor_data.rolling(window=1,freq="1MIN")`. For the most part it works fine, but there are two types of irregularities I can't overcome for certain types of functions. Specifically, either:

1. No output for incomplete minutes -- It doesn't given an output for minutes that don't have all 60 seconds. This is the case for the `mean(), quantile(), sum()`
2. No output at all. For certain functions like `var(), std(), kurt(), skew()`, I don't get any values at all. I really can't understand why this would be the case given that it was able to calculate the mean...

Other functions seem to work without a problem: `max(), median(), min()`

**I really care about the 2nd problem, but it would be a bonus to get a workaround for the 1st as well...**

---

```
sensor_data.head()

    x_acceleration  y_acceleration  z_acceleration  heart_rate  electrodermal_activity  temperature
index                       
2016-05-16 06:58:44 -33.25000   -43.03125   33.09375    NaN 0.297099    33.33
2016-05-16 06:58:45 -28.15625   -52.90625   24.12500    NaN 0.219612    33.33
2016-05-16 06:58:46 -25.87500   -55.96875   21.18750    NaN 0.222648    33.33
2016-05-16 06:58:47 -24.00000   -57.46875   19.40625    NaN 0.217335    33.33
2016-05-16 06:58:48 -22.84375   -56.25000   23.40625    NaN 0.214300    33.33
```

Example output of the 1st case -- no output for incomplete minute:

```
sensor_data.rolling(window=1,freq="1MIN").mean().head()
    x_acceleration  y_acceleration  z_acceleration  heart_rate  electrodermal_activity  temperature
index                       
2016-05-16 06:58:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2016-05-16 06:59:00 -24.84375   -59.46875   9.03125 68.57   0.208988    33.75
2016-05-16 07:00:00 6.31250 -62.78125   6.46875 79.40   0.224924    33.84
2016-05-16 07:01:00 -21.18750   -57.00000   22.50000    92.00   0.224165    34.13
2016-05-16 07:02:00 -17.46875   -58.87500   21.84375    81.10   0.224165    34.25
```

Example output of the 2nd case -- no output:

```
sensor_data.rolling(window=1,freq="1MIN").var().head()

    x_acceleration  y_acceleration  z_acceleration  heart_rate  electrodermal_activity  temperature
index                       
2016-05-16 06:58:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2016-05-16 06:59:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2016-05-16 07:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2016-05-16 07:01:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2016-05-16 07:02:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for starters, this will get you going.

```
sensor_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='Min')).describe()
```

you can build a custom function:

```
def stats(df):
    kurt = pd.DataFrame(df.kurt(), columns=['kurt']).T
    skew = pd.DataFrame(df.skew(), columns=['skew']).T
    var = pd.DataFrame(df.var(), columns=['var']).T
    return pd.concat([df.describe(), var, skew, kurt])
```

then:

```
sensor_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='Min')).apply(stats)
```

[image]

---

EDIT:

Incorporated @Jeff's comment:

```
funcs = {
    'Count': 'count',
    'Var': np.var,
    'Std': np.std,
    'Mean': np.mean,
    'Min': np.min,
    '25%': lambda x: x.quantile(.25),
    '50%': np.median,
    '75%': lambda x: x.quantile(.75),
    'Max': np.max,
    'Skew': 'skew',
    'Kurt': lambda x: x.kurt(),
}

cols = sensor_data.columns
```

This is a comprehensive list of functions.

```
sensor_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='Min')).agg({c: funcs for c in cols}).stack()
```

Looks like:

[image]

#### Timing

```
%%timeit
sensor_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='Min')).agg({c: funcs for c in cols}).stack()

10 loops, best of 3: 121 ms per loop

%%timeit
sensor_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='Min')).apply(stats).dropna()

1 loop, best of 3: 221 ms per loop
```

It looks like `agg` is about twice as fast.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much! I've been at this for hours... I also used your setup to get the individual functions like this: sensor_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='Min')).var() (

Comment: using apply is not idiomatic and this is non performant; .agg with the function names (kurt, skew is much more preferred

Comment: @Jeff Can you clarify a) the scale of how big the performance gain is? b) how to implement i appropriately? When replaced apply with agg, I ended up getting this error: "ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 6 to array axis with dimension 11"

Comment: @piRSquared already updated; the issue is that ``.apply`` is opaque and is in python space, while ``.agg`` when given function names e.g. ``kurt`` can be highly performant. Furthermore it is much more idiomatic / readable.